# IOReactorShutdownException: I/O reactor has been shut down, using apache httpclient5

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

we recently upgraded our httpclient version from 4.x to 5.0.3.

The main reason for the upgrade is to get rid of the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED` exception that accures on version 4.x.

After the upgrade, for some unknown reason we are experiencing this error now:

```
22:35:04,160 (pool-9-thread-1] ERROR http.async.HttpAsyncSender - Unable to send request, cause-I/O reactor has been shut down

org.apache.ha.cores.reactor. IOReactorShutdownException: I/O reactor has been shut down at org.apache.ho.cores.reactor.AbstractIOReactorBase.connect(AbstractIOReactorBase.java:50)-thespoores-5.0.2.341/15.0.21

at org.apache.ha.clients.http.impl.nio.Maltihome105essionRequesterfi.executellext (Multihome10Sessionequester.java:105) -[httpolients-5.0.3.3art/25.0.31 37021 at org.apache.he.clients.http.impl.nic.MultihomeI0SessionRequester$1.run (Multihome105essionRequester.java:153) -(httpclients-5.0.3.jar/15.0.3)

at org.apache.hc.clients.http.impl.nio.Multihome10SessionRequester.connect (Multihome 10dessionequester-java:157)-[httpclient5-5.0.3.Jaz1/15.0.31 at org.apache.he.clients.http.impl.nio.DefaultAsyncClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultAsyncClientConnectionOperator.java:30) -[httpclients-5.0.3.jar!/15.0.3)

at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.connect (FoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.java:369) -[httpclients-5.0.3.jar!/15.0.3)

at org.apache.he.clients.http.impl.wayng.InternalfetpAsyncExecRuntime.connectEndpoint (InternalttpAsynckxeckuntime.JAVA:210)-[httpclients-5.0.3-3art/15.0.31 at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec.proceedTolfextop (AsyncConnectExec.java:195) -httpeltent5-5.0.3.jar/5.0.31

at org.apache.ba.clients.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec.access2000 (AsyncConnectExec.java:79)-[httpclients-5.0.3.jar/15.0.3) at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl-axyng.AsyncConnectExec.completed (AsyncConnectExec.java:146) -Thespelients-5.0.3.jar!/15.0.3)

at org.apache.bo.clients.http-impl-async.AsyncConnectExecli.completed (AsyncConnectExec.java:135) -(httpelients-5.0.3.jar!/15.0.3)

at org.apache.hc.clients.http.impl.axyng.InternalttpAsyncExecRuntimesi.completed (InternalNetpayncExecRuntime.java:114) -[httpclients-3.0.3.3art/15.0.3) at org.apache.bo.clients.http.impl.async.InternalfetpAryncExecRuntime1.completed [InternalttpAsyncExecRuntime.java:105) -(httpaliest5-5.0.3.jar!/15.0.31

at org.apache.bc.cores.concurrent.Basicfuture.completed (Basicfuture.java:123) (httpoores-5.0.2.jar!/15.0.21 at org.apache.hc.cores.concurrent.ComplexFuture.completed (Complexfuture.179) (httpceres-5.0.2.jart/:5.0.21

at peg.apache.he.clients.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager$1. leaseCompleted (PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.java:240) -[httpclients-5.0.3.3art/15.0.31

at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager$1.completed/FoolingAayneClientConnectionManager.JATA1275)-[httpclients-3.0.3.3az1/15.0.31 at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager$1.completed(PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.java:224) -[httpclients-8.0.3.jar!/15.0.31

at org.apache.bs.cores.concurrent.Basicfuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:123) -[httpeores-5.0.2.3art/15.0.23

at org.apache.hc.cores.pool.strictConnPool.fireCallbacks (StrictConnPool.java:383) -(httpcore5-5.0.2.jar!/15.0.23 at org.apache.hc-cores.pool.strictcoonPool.Inase (Strict ConnPool.java:199)-[httpcores-5.0.2.jar!/15.0.21

TRAR at org.apache.bo.clients.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.lease (Foolinghayn ClientConnectionManager.java:225) (httpclients-5.0.3.3421/15.0.3) at org.apache.ho.clients.http.impl.anng.InternallttpyncExecRuntime.squireEndpoint (Internal:twyncExecuntime.java:100)-[httpclients-3.0.1.jart/25.0.31 at org.apache.he.clients.http.impl.async-AsyncConnectExec.execute(AsyncConnectExec.java:134)-[httpclients-5.0.2.jar/15.0.
```

We have no idea why this error accures or what is causing it.

The only major diffference between our version was that in the previus version with httpclient 4.x, we consumed the response:

httpclient 4.x code:

```java
@override
public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
    // some code ...
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```

but now we use `SimpleHttpResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` and `getEntity()` is not a function of `SimpleHttpResponse`, so we removed this code.

So my question is, why the error above hppends? can it be related to the fact that we do not consume the response? and if so - why is it related? when do you need to use `consume()`?

Comment: did you get to solve this?

Comment: Yes the solution is to wrap the request in try catch.

Comment: @NoyGafni can you provide a snippet? Why is it the solution? Seems not really natural.